# Query for grouping of successful attempts when order matters

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

Let's say, for example, I have a db table Jumper for tracking high jumpers.  It has three columns of interest: attempt_id, athlete, and result (a boolean for whether the jumper cleared the bar or not).

I want to write a query that will compare all athletes' performance across different attempts yielding a table with this information: attempt number, number of cleared attempts, total attempts.  In other words, what is the chance that an athlete will clear the bar on x attempt.

What is the best way of writing this query?  It is trickier than it would seem at first because you need to determine the attempt number for each athlete to be able to total the final totals.

I would prefer answers be written with Django ORM, but SQL will also be accepted.

Edit: To be clear, I need it to be grouped by attempt, not by athlete.  So it would be all athletes' combined x attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it using SQL:

```
SELECT t.attempt_id,
       SUM(CASE t.result WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cleared,
       COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM Jumper t
 GROUP BY t.attempt_id
```

**EDIT:** If attempt_id is just a sequence, and you want to use it to calculate the attempt number for each jumper, you could use this query instead:

```
SELECT t.attempt_number,
       SUM(CASE t.result WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cleared,
       COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM (SELECT s.*,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY athlete
                                 ORDER BY attempt_id) AS attempt_number
        FROM Jumper s) t
 GROUP BY t.attempt_number
```

This way, you group every first attempt from all athletes, every second attempt from all athletes, and so on...

Comment: I added an edit in case my original write up didn't make sense, but I need results to be grouped by attempt, not athlete.  That way, I can find the percentage of first attempts that are correct across all athletes, for example.